# How do you handle SSL certificate store with Python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ssl, certificate, amazon-rds

We are using python here to connect to an AWS RDS database, the connection requires SSL cert, we are already doing the same with java, just added the certificate to java's default CA store.

was searching on how to do the same with python (where is the default CA store and how to add certs there) but couldn't find it unfortunately, is python even works that way? or do i need to provide a cert path for every time i want to use it (or maybe configuring it for java might be enough? though i doubt it)?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this help you? https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/configure-boto-to-validate-https-certificates/

Comment: Which OS are you on? And which database engine are you talking to?

Comment: I'm on Amazon linux and im using mysql engine

Comment: @furkanayd i saw that and it looked promising but then im not sure where and how i add my cert to the ca-store? i used ssl.get_default_verify_paths() but that returns a bunch of different places to add my cert, do i use keytool to do it? or do i copy them to the directory? also is python using SSL by default?

Comment: @Matan you have define you AWS connection paramaters into boto config such as (proxy, ca_certfication_file, is_secure, etc.) then try to use boto to connect your AWS. As reffered in here : http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/boto_config_tut.html#boto

Comment: @furkanayd im not using boto to connect to the rds (using a spark module) so im not sure this is relevant